# Does anyone know how to Stuff in groups?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to use the stuff function in MS SQL to stuff certain info. Here is the example:

```
Number          Value 
1                 1
2                 1
3                 1
1                 2
2                 2
3                 2
1                 3
2                 3
```

I would like to stuff the column so that only one record will display as following:

```
Value             Number
1                 1,2,3
2                 1,2,3
3                 1,2
```

Please note that there are a like n-Numbers and n-Values.

Comment: [group_concat](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function in MySQL will work. You have tagged this as MySQL but you stated MS SQL, what DB are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) for this. For example:

```
SELECT `Value`, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT `Number` ORDER BY `Number`)
FROM `yourTable`
GROUP BY `Value`
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help.
Still I get an error. My query looks like this:

SELECT 
    'value'
   ,GROUP_CONCAT(distinct 'number' order by 'number')
 FROM 'table1'
  JOIN 'table2' -- i need to join the table in order to get the data together 
  JOIN 'table3' -- i need to join the table in order to get the data together
  GROUP BY 'value'

Something seems to be wrong with the ' GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT `Number` ORDER BY `Number`)' - because the rest of the query seems fine and i can excute. thanks for every help!

Comment: @user2664537 You should really post a different question for that and include the error.